# Remove Delay for ios textPassword

Tags: ios, passwords

While enterting password inside EditText view, Characters are being shown and after some delay it is shown as DOT, i want to remove this delay. It should be displayed directly as DOT.

How do i do this on ios?

Comment: That's just how secure text field works; It is important for usability as it gives the user an opportunity to confirm they have typed the correct character.  To change the behaviour you would need to create your own text field control.

Comment: how can i create my text field control? is there any options i can control delay on input tag in html??

Comment: In a native app I would try implementing the `textFieldDidChange` delegate, tracking the characters entered in another variable and replacing them with dots manually.  In HTML I doubt there is anything much you can do.  As I said, there is a very good reason why the text field behaves in the way it does.